# Create sorting dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Write the function dataframe that takes a
dictionary as input and creates a dataframe
from the dictionary, Sort the dictionary.

Instructions

```
1. Create a dataframe with the input dictionary
2. Columns should be Name Age
3. Print "Before Sorting"
4. Print a Newline
5. Print the dataframe before sorting. 
Note: Printing the dataframe must not contain index.
6. Print a Newline
7. Sort the dataframe in ascending order based on Age column
8. Print "After Sorting"
9. Print a Newline
10. Print the dataframe after sorting. Note: Printing the dataframe must not contain index.
```

Sample Input (it may change according to use cases. So cannot insert below input on code)

['william':42, 'George' :10, 'Joseph
:22, 'Henry':15, 'Samuel':32, 'David':18]

Sample Output

Before Sorting

Name    Age

William  42

George. 10

Joseph. 22

Henry.  15

Samuel. 32

David.  18

After Sorting

Name.  Age

George. 10

Henry.  15

David.  18

Joseph. 22

Samuel. 32

William. 42

import pandas
import ast

#Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output from STDOUT

def dataframe(key, value):
.  STDIN = {key:value}

Comment: I think the idea is that you should write the function `dataframe`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dataframe(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print("Before Sorting")
    print(df)
    df.sort_values(by=['Age'], inplace=True)
    print("After Sorting")
    print(df)
```

Output :

```
Before Sorting
      Name  Age
0  William   42
1   George   10
2   Joseph   22
3    Henry   15
4   Samuel   32
5    David   18
After Sorting
      Name  Age
1   George   10
3    Henry   15
5    David   18
2   Joseph   22
4   Samuel   32
0  William   42
```